# apex_util.get_blob was not found on this server

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to develop an interactive report in which I am using blob column to download the blob file (that could be jpeg or pdf). I created the download field on the blob column but, when I clicked on it, it gives an error as mentioned below.
"**The requested URL /apex/apex_util.get_blob was not found on this server**"

Note: I am using oracle apex 5.1.2.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that BLOB column is named `BLOB_COLUMN`, and it contains JPEG or PDF. It is one of column in SELECT statement you used to create an interactive report.

By default, BLOB_COLUMN's type is "Plain text". If you just changed it to `Download BLOB` and filled required BLOB attributes, well - it won't work.

Instead, you should create yet another column in IR's SELECT:

```
select ...,
  dbms_lob.getlength(blob_column) download_blob
from ...
```

and apply BLOB attributes to it. I've just tried it on apex.oracle.com, works as expected. If it still doesn't work for you, please, create an example on the same site, provide credentials so that someone of us might have a look.

Comment: the problem is.. when i am doing the same thing on apex cloud then it is running fine and file has been downloaded successfully. But, when I am running it on my oracle 12c db server it is giving me that error.
"The requested URL /apex/apex_util.get_blob was not found on this server"

Comment: Do I need to give any permissions to the user or the schema which I am using for the interactive report?

Comment: Apart from EXECUTE ON DBMS_LOB? I don't think so (or, to be more precise, I wouldn't know).

Comment: Can you please explain how would you give execute on dbms_lob?

Comment: Connect as a privileged user (such as SYS) and issue `grant execute on dbms_lob to your_user;`

Answer (score 0):

at the BLOB attributes there is a Primary key column. The get_blob uses the same column value from the report to fetch the blob from the given table. So, if you have two ID columns in two tables (joined report) you have to create a view for the other table and use an other column name as ID in  it. Use this view and the new ID column name as a PK.